# NodeJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express.js

Sou iniciante em NodeJs e me deparei com esse problema quando fui exportar um modulo: **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"**. Não entendi porque deu o erro já que o código está idêntico ao do professor do curso, mas ainda assim ocorre o erro. Atualmente o código está assim:

```
module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/noticias', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('noticias/noticias')
  })
}
```

Quando eu faço o `require` do módulo o servidor não sobe, dando esse erro que comentei. Espero que possam me ajudar, agradeço desde já :)

Comment: Onde você está fazendo a chamada dessa rota que está definindo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa definir `app` (que é uma instância do `express`), exemplo:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.get('/noticias', (req, res)=>{
  res.render('noticias/noticias')
})
```

O que o pessoal costuma fazer também é definir `app` como global:

```
// arquivo1.js
let express = require('express');
global.app = express();
```

Para usar:

```
// arquivo2.js
require('arquivo1.js')
module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/noticias', (req, res)=>{
     res.render('noticias/noticias')
  })
}
```